# react native - why is my console.log returning [] but items get rendered on screen?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to access the object obtained from my API get request but I keep getting Array[] returned in the console.log while the items get rendered on the screen.

Can someone spot where I went wrong?

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
  setLoading(false);
  if (refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
  if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
  setError(false);
  setPosts(response.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  const newsocket = io.connect("http://ip:port");
  loadPosts();
  console.log(posts); // not working
  newsocket.on("connect", (msg) => {
    setSocket(newsocket);
  });

  return () => newsocket.close();
}, []);

return (
  <FlatList
    data={posts}
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
      <MessagesList
        title={item.title}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT, { message: item, index, updateView })
        }
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

Comment: try changing `loadPosts()` to `await loadPosts()` inside your `useEffect ` call and also adding `posts` to `useEffect``s dependency array

Comment: @emkarachchi hi, thank you for getting back to me, i got an error. i thought it is not best practise to call async and await inside useEffect?

Comment: Yes. adding `posts` to the dependency array will fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE**

`console.log` executes before getting an API response.

**SOLUTION**

`console.log` would work when you add `posts` in dependency like

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(posts); 
}, [posts]); // added posts here
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. when do i use loadPosts() ?

Comment: @kd12345 `loadPosts` work same as it working like, add another `useEffect` method as above and try

Comment: WORKS :) thank you Nooruddin, but do you mind explaining why having only 1 useEffect doesnt work?

Comment: So in the first useEffect i make my API call and in my second useEffect i console.log(posts) when posts changes, so first the screen loads and clg(posts) is undefined then when the API is called screen loads again clg(posts) prints the posts? But in other screens i had both in the same useEffect and it was working.